# Use local audio files in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, audio

I'm building a Chrome extension and want local audio to play on `mouseenter`.

Right now, I'm loading and calling the audio file in my `content.js` (the js file in my `content_scripts`) like so:

```
var audioEl = document.createElement('audio');
  audioEl.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
  audioEl.setAttribute("src", "/.../audio_1.mp3");
  audioEl.setAttribute("id", "audio_1");
...
// mouseenter any h1 and run this function
$("h1").mouseenter(function(event){
  if (event.target == this){
    // enlarge the hovered-over h1 element
    $(this).css("transform", "scale(2)").css("transition-duration", "4s");
    // and play the audio_1 file
    $("#audio_1").play();
```

I've added the following to my general `permissions` in my `manifest.json` file

```
"permissions": [ 
   "<all_urls>", 
   "file:///*/*", 
   "file://*/*" 
]
```

This causes an error either by applying the path for the audio file to the website itself or to `chrome-extension://`

I can't find a solution on SO or anywhere else. In the documentation, it looks like Google has disabled the use of any local audio/video files in the current version of Chrome.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Should I host the audio files elsewhere and link to them? Maybe preloading the audio file in the `background.html`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.